# Changing the extension of multiple files to jpeg using C#

Tags: c#, .net, jpeg

I am trying to change the extension of files within a folder to jpeg. I have used the below code to update the extension and it is working fine. But when i try to open each of the files, I am getting the error in photo viewer as "Windows photo viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted or its too large."

```
 DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\New folder (2)");
                FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles(); 
                string str = "";
                foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
                {
                    str = str + ", " + file.Name;
                    string changed =  Path.ChangeExtension(file.FullName, ".jpg");
                    File.WriteAllText(changed, "Changed file");
                }
```

Comment: _"I am trying to change the extension of files within a folder"_ - that smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you call a car a cow, can you put it in the meat grinder? What ultimate problem are you solving? Do you want to convert an image's format? Or aren't the files images to begin with?

Comment: Changing the extension does not magically make it a picture.

Comment: What is the *original* extension of the file? You can´t expect a text-file to become an image just because you *call* it image. In your case the file already has to be a jpg, not a bitmap or tiff or whatefer.

Comment: I just now noticed the `File.WriteAllText(changed, "Changed file");`. Did you bother opening one of the newly created files in a text editor? Why are you writing the string "Changed file" into the file? What is this code supposed to do? You're claiming you want to rename files, but you're doing something else entirely.

Comment: What are the extensions of the files you're trying to change?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp... i know i cant magically convert any file to a jpeg file. I have tried renaming the same file manually and added the .jpeg extension and it was converted to the image file and i was able to view it. But when i do it through code, i get this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPEG files are not text files. You need to Read and write bytes instead. ie:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\New folder (2)");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles(); 

foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
   string changed =  Path.ChangeExtension(file.FullName, "jpg");
   File.Copy(file.FullName, changed);
}
```

Of course file themselves should be JPEG for this to work.

Comment: That would leave the original file, if that wasn't required then File.Move would just rename the file.

Comment: @PaulF, Yes obviously it is a "Copy".

Comment: _"Changing the extension of multiple files"_ seems to imply OP wants to rename rather than copy - so just adding a comment to help if that is required.

Comment: @PaulF, Yes you are right, I was scared to write a "rename" operation after seeing his code. Maybe I shouldn't do protective assumptions.